# Calculated column where I have one table of data

Tags: powerbi

I've got one table of data.  The columns are:

- ID (unique)
- Issue_ID
- Field (filtered to be just "status")
- Old_Status
- New_Status
- Record_Date

I need an calculated value for each record:  Difference in Record_Date where Issue_IDs match and Old_Status matches New_Status in the older record.

Is this possible?

Sample data:

```
ID     Issue_ID  FIELD   Old_Status  New_Status  Record_Date
------------------------------------------------------------
24960  DCA‌​-1     status  Backlog     Pl‌​anned     10/19/2017
24961  DCA-1     status  Planned     Analysis    10/19/2017
24962  DCA-1     status  Analysis    Execution   10/22/2017
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. 
 I can't seem to get that 
 working...

ID,Issue_ID,FIELD,Old_Status,New_Status,Record_Date  
24960,DCA-1,status,Backlog,Planned,10/19/2017  
24961,DCA-1,status,Planned,Analysis,10/19/2017  
24962,DCA-1,status,Analysis,Execution,10/22/2017

Comment: OK. So you want to return null, 0, and 3 for rows 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: Correct.  As a column in that table or another query that I can work with.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the previous data using `LOOKUPVALUE`:

```
PreviousRecord = LOOKUPVALUE(Data[Record_Date],Data[Issue_ID],Data[Issue_ID],Data[New_Status],Data[Old_Status])
```

You can then use this value to compute a `DATEDIFF`:

```
DATEDIFF(PreviousRecord,Data[Record_Date],DAY)
```

or expanded out:

```
Difference in Date = DATEDIFF(LOOKUPVALUE(Data[Record_Date],Data[Issue_ID],Data[Issue_ID],Data[New_Status],Data[Old_Status]),Data[Record_Date],DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, when I attempt to create a custom column, I get: Expression.Error: The name 'DATEDIFF' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Comment: OK, instead of editing the query, I went to the Modeling tab to do this.  Now, I get "In DATEDIFF function, the start date cannot be greater than the end date."

Comment: @MikePulsifer Sounds like you have some rows where the new status happened before the old status. Maybe try subtraction to find: Data[Record_Date] - PreviousRecord